# Generic Type argument is not within bounds

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm working on a little demo android app where I mix some java classes and interfaces with kotlin. I want to extend from a java class with generic type arguments called `MvpViewStateActivity`:

```
abstract class MvpViewStateActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V> > { ... }
```

where `MvpView` is just an empty java interface:

```
interface MvpView { ... }
```

and `MvpPresenter` is an java interface like this:

```
interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> { ... }
```

and `SearchViewActivity` (Java):

```
class SearchActivity extends MvpViewStateActivity<SearchView, SearchPresenter>
                     implements SearchView { ... }
```

So now I create a kotlin interface `SearchView`:

```
interface SearchView : MvpView { 
    fun setItems( items : List<Item> )
 }
```

where `Item` is a pojo data class.

`SearchPresenter` is written in kotlin as well:

```
interface SearchPresenter : MvpPresenter<SearchView> { ... }
```

So to sum it up:

Java classes:

- MvpViewStateActivity
- MvpView
- MvpPresenter
- SearchViewActivity

Kotlin classes / interfaces

- SearchView extends MvpView (java)
- SearchPresenter extends MvpPresenter (java)

When I try to compile that code I get the following error:

> error: type argument SearchView is not within bounds of type-variable
>   V where V is a type-variable: V extends MvpView declared in class
>   MvpViewStateActivity

But `SearchView : MvpView` (in other words `SearchView extends MvpView`).

The compiler points to that line of code:

SearchActivity extends MvpViewStateActivity<**SearchView**

Am I overlooking something?
Is this a kotlin bug?

Comment: your `SearchActivity` is written in java, not in kotlin. What did you ment?

Comment: Could you also fix the formatting please?

Comment: Also need to see `SearchPresenter`.

Comment: I have added the `SearchPresenter` (kotlin interface), but the compile error clearly points  SearchActivity's first generic type parameter

Comment: @voddan yes, that was an error in the description, `SearchActivity` is written in java but the `SearchView` interface has been written in kotlin. The compile error is in `SearchActivity` saying that `SearchView` is `not within bounds of type-variable V where V is a type-variable: V extends MvpView`, but `SearchView : MvpView`

Comment: it might be a good idea to show us the methods of your interfaces. as @vanOekel said, your code throws no error if we assume the interfaces are empty. but they are not, judging by `...` everywhere

Comment: @sockeqwe even if you resolve this problem, please describe your solution here. I suspect that kotlinc is doing its job, but the error message is incomprehensible. That's a thing to fix

Comment: @voddan I haven't found a solution yet, but I assume that kotlinc's error message is wrong. Of course I will post a solution once I'm sure that I have found one.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the "not within bounds" issue.

This is the first time I use Kotlin, so let me explain what I did so you can verify.
I changed the class-names for clarity.

Using Java 7, Eclipse, create a Java project with a package "generics".
Create two files:

```
package generics;
public interface IView {}
```

and

```
package generics;
public interface IPresenter<VIEW extends IView> {}
```

Download Kotlin compiler version 1.0.0-beta-2423, extract and copy `IView.class` and `IPresenter.class` from the project "bin\generics" folder into a new "kotlin\generics" folder.
Create `KGenericViewPresenter.kt` in the "kotlin\generics" folder:

```
package generics

interface ISearchView : IView {}
interface ISearchPresenter : IPresenter<ISearchView> {}
```

Run: 

`bin\kotlinc -cp . generics\KGenericViewPresenter.kt`

Back in the Java project, add class folder "fromkotlin", create a "generics" folder in it and copy 
`ISearchView.class` and `ISearchPresenter.class` from the "kotlin\generics" folder.

Refresh the Java project (so that the two new classes from Kotlin are picked up).

Create two new files in the Java project:

```
package generics;
public abstract class AbstractViewStateActivity<VIEW extends IView, PRESENTER extends IPresenter<VIEW>> {}
```

and

```
package generics;
public class ViewStateActivity extends AbstractViewStateActivity<ISearchView, ISearchPresenter> 
    implements ISearchView {}
```

Eclipse does not complain, the project's "bin\generics" folder contains files `AbstractViewStateActivity.class` and `ViewStateActivity.class`.

If this is a valid test, try refreshing your IDE environment and also make sure there is no class in the package with the name `V` or `P`  (also check unit-test classes).

Comment: I guess I have found the real issue: The problem is that `ISearchView` defines a method `fun setItems(items: List<Item>)` where `Item` is any arbitrary POJO class.  This translates to `public void setItems(List<? extends Item> items)` in java and NOT `public void setItems(List<Item> items)`. Can you confirm that by adding such a method you face the same issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why `not within bounds` is the printed error

Comment: @sockeqwe Can confirm, when I let Eclipse "add the unimplemented method" I get `void setItems(List<? extends ItemPojo> arg0)` in Java, but otherwise no errors.

Comment: hm, strange, I'm using android studio 1.5 with kotlin 1.0.0-beta-2423
I will test your sample code tomorrow in Android Studio. Thanks!